# Read File stored on some URL using HTML5 File API

Tags: javascript, html, filereader, html5-filesystem

I'm using HTML5 file API to upload files to my web application.

I have an input element on my web page using which I read files and call upload function

```
<input type="file">

$('input[type="file"]').on("change",function(e){
      console.log(this.files);
      // upload each file in this.files
});
```

This works perfectly for native files on os. I want to now upload remote files e.g., example.com/blah/file1.jpg My question is how do I read this file using File API? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Just a provide a TextBox for the user to paste the URL. Then on the server side you can retrieve the file based on the URL.

Comment: no this has to be done on client side, it's a browser extension. I need to download the file first into user's browser and then upload.

Comment: Why do you need to download to the user's computer, then upload to a server? That's an extra step. Storing it in JavaScript's memory would be bad performance wise, as well as eating up the user's bandwidth.

Comment: because I don't own the server... I need to send them actual bits of the file in order to upload.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download remote files over `XMLHttpRequest`, and process them as `Blob`. Then upload it to another server. The upload has to be over `XMLHttpRequest`. It relies on the browser's implementation of XHR Level 2. This link contains the code snippets you will need:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

It has both snippets for downloading remote file as a `Blob` and uploading a `Blob` to a server.

Comment: thanks tiger, it worked like a charm except I lose all the metadata when I say var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'image/png'}); how do I get the filename after doing this?

Comment: @sublime: I don't think there's "filename" if we are retrieving a file over network. Say it's `/download?id=1234`, there's no filename at all. So you need to set up your own rules about getting the filename. You can follow what most browsers do: 1. Take the last part of the URI path and treat it as a file; 2. If `content-disposition` exists in response header, follow the standard and use what's in it as filename.

Comment: Thanks, one last question: some image urls that I'm getting are base64 encoded data strings. data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ... and when that's the case browser throws an error saying XMLHttpRequest cannot load data:image, cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. How do I download those images?

Comment: nevermind, I found this on how to convert dataURI to image blob http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata